# the difference in terms of performance two types of update in opensearch

Tags: performance, opensearch

The opensearch allows us to update given document in two ways.

1. PUT index/_doc/1 (replaces whole document)
2. POST index/_update/1 (allows for partial update)

I conducted tests to observe concurrent updates on a single document. Interestingly, PUT requests consistently succeed, while POST requests trigger a version_conflict_engine_exception. Although this exception is expected, it raises questions about potential additional overhead in the update API. Unfortunately, I couldn’t find relevant information. Can you advise which method performs better in terms of execution performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html)
This operation **indexes the result**.

```
PUT index/_doc/1
```

> When updating a document using the index API a new version of the document is always created even if the document hasn’t changed.

[_update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html)

```
POST index/_update/1
```

This operation:

1. **Gets the document (collocated with the shard) from the index.**
2. **Runs the specified script.**
3. **Indexes the result.**

As a result, because Index API need less operation than Update API call, the Index API, `PUT index/_doc/1`, will perform better than Update API, `POST index/_update/1`.

---

About VersionConflictException:

Index operations can be made conditional and only be performed if the last modification to the document was assigned the sequence number and primary term specified by the if_seq_no and if_primary_term parameters. If a mismatch is detected, the operation will result in a VersionConflictException and a status code of 409. See [Optimistic concurrency control](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/optimistic-concurrency-control.html) for more details.

**When updating a document using the index API a new version of the document is always created even if the document hasn’t changed.** If this isn’t acceptable use the _update API with detect_noop set to true. This option isn’t available on the index API because the index API doesn’t fetch the old source and isn’t able to compare it against the new source.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-noop

Comment: you shared the links to elasticsearch documentation. Does it mean that elasticsearch documentation can be used as a reference to OpenSearch way of of working?

Comment: Opensearch is fork of Elasticsearch at version 7.10.2. Yes you can use **some documentation** as a reference point from elasticsearch for opensearch but you should know the history of that API calls. Because after v7.10.2 OS and ES are different products and not compatible each others.
https://aws.amazon.com/tr/blogs/opensource/introducing-opensearch/
https://www.elastic.co/elasticsearch/opensearch

*Please note that the only way to make sure about it is deep dive into the source code.*